# Xcode 4.5.2 Builds But Won't Archive

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to get my Xcode workspace containing an app + 2 static libraries to archive successfully. Everything builds just fine. I've followed this Apple document verbatim [Using Static Libraries in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html) and it works great with builds but the archive always leaves 1 header file it can't find.

I've probably looked at all the other posts related and have tried the many permutations of dragging in the header files, using Copy Headers build phases, changing the User Header Search Paths to all sorts of derivatives, etc. It seems there is no "proper" way to resolve this.

I'm at my witz end here. Willing to try any additional recommendations.

Comment: if the destination is not a _real_ device (therefore: the destination is the simulator), you **cannot** archive with any version of Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue here. I just could resolve it by the following.

In the copy headers build phase of the library there are different sections, Public, Private and Project. All headers that were affected (i.e. recognized in the build but ignored for the archive) were in the Project section. Dragging them to the Public section did the trick for me.